# Why the computational time of random forest is lower than the decision tree?

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, cart

What I understood is that RF trains many decision trees. RF supposes to have higher training and testing time.

Based on my experiments, it seems like RF have a lower computational time.

Is this possible to happen?

Comment: This sounds unlikely. The only explanation could be that random forest may be configured to train much simpler trees than single decision tree. Could you give us more details?

Comment: agreed, this is exceptionally unlikely. It is possible however, that you could get comparable training time. Random Forests are quite trivial to parallelise. If you are working on a 16 core machine and you train a random forest with 16 estimators, it likely won't take much longer to train than a single decision tree